# How to open application android programmatically if i don't know package name

Tags: android

I know to open an application pro grammatically we can do this :

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

However, how to do it if I don't know the package name; just the application name ?

Thanks!

Edit: I tried to get package name by opening the app and checking logs but the package name didn't show up.

Comment: How would you handle applications that have the same application name ?

Comment: @pskink can you explain more how to do it ? Maybe some code ?

Comment: use `getInstalledApplications` from the `PackageManager` to retrieve all installed applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this would help, but I have to add that this is a terrible approach as app names can be the same for different apps, and some apps (like "Contacts") have different labels based on the language set

```
     /**
     *
     * @param appName The target app to launch, if there are multiple apps with same name, the first found will be launched
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the target app was not found
     */
    public void runApp(String appName) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        for ( ResolveInfo info : getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0) ) {
            if ( info.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).equals(appName) ) {
                Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
                startActivity(launchIntent);
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Application not found!");
    }
```